# Creating shell script to print weekday and weekend

Tags: shell-script

How to create a simple program using for loop and if.

my code:

```
for i in mon tue wed thurs fri sat 
do
   echo weekday: $i
   if [ $i == thurs ]   
   then
      echo weekend: $i+1
   fi
done
```

and the output:

```
weekday: mon
weekday: tue
weekday: wed
weekday: thurs
weekend: thurs+1
weekday: fri
weekday: sat
```

However, I want to have an output like:

```
weekday: mon
weekday: tue
weekday: wed
weekday: thurs
weekend: fri
weekend: sat
```

Which syntax did I missed ?

Answer (score 5):

Given code:

```
for i in mon tue wed thurs fri sat 
do
 echo weekday: $i
  if [ $i == thurs ]    
    then
    echo weekend: $i+1
  fi
done
```

- `echo weekday: $i` gets called every iteration
- The `for` loop yields an element every iteration to `i` variable. `i` is not an array index as you might have expected

Different ways to get your expected output:

1) do a string comparison

```
for i in mon tue wed thurs fri sat 
do
    if [ $i == fri ] || [ $i == sat ]
    then
        echo weekend: $i
    else
        echo weekday: $i
    fi
done
```

2) Use a string to save the prefix and modify it depending on a condition

```
s='weekday'
for i in mon tue wed thurs fri sat 
do
    echo "$s: $i"
    if [ $i == thurs ]
    then
        s='weekend'
    fi
done
```

3) Use an array

```
days=(mon tue wed thurs fri sat)

for ((i=0; i<${#days[@]}; i++))
do
    if (( i < 4 ))
    then
        echo "weekday: ${days[$i]}"
    else
        echo "weekend: ${days[$i]}"
    fi
done
```